# How can I run my Python Script in Siteground Hosting Server

Tags: python, selenium

I am building my website which contains a python(.py) file, html, css and JS file. I want to know that how can I run my python script in siteground from my hosting account so that it can scrape data from a site and output a JSON file to Javascript file which can display it on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cron jobs to run jobs in the foreground